# iphone application international sales

Tags: iphone, internationalization, translation

Would anyone be able to give a "best practices" summary for creating an app targeted internationally?

1. How to prepare the app for translations "espanol, english, korean, chinese etc.)
2. What sort of measures do you need in the approval process? do you submit one APP or is it several?
3. How to optimize your iTunes store page to work across different languages.

all the best!

Answer (score 4):

This is actually [pretty well documented by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html). Basically you don't hardcode strings in your program. You put them in a separate file (in a particular format) and use `NSLocalisedString` in your code. You can also localise your NIB files if you need to. Date handling is pretty much automatic if you use the correct APIs.

You submit a single application. The app bundle can contain many localisations.

iTunes Connect allows you to write a different page in each store/language.

The "best practice," I guess, is to follow Apple's guide. The only piece of advice I would add is don't rely on computer translation; get a real person to do it if you can't do it yourself. Google is pretty good but you don't want anything embarrassing slipping through!